# Is there a way in Redshift to extract all URLs from a block of text each as a separate row?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to extract all URLs of a certain format from a block of text that may contain 0, 1, or lots of URLs.

For example, one row may have the value:

*'some text
blahblahblah.com
more text
secondwebsite.com
more test'*

And I would want that represented in my output as two rows:

*'blahblahblah.com'*

*'secondwebsite.com'*

I can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `SPLIT_PART` to get just the first `.com` occurrence, but ideally I'd be able to extract all occurrences separately. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning multiple output rows from a single input row is not easy in SQL.

You would need to cross-join to a numeric table (eg a table that contains rows containing `1, 2, 3...`, and then use that number to reference a separate part of the input row.

**Bottom line:** It is possible, but it is messy. Try to find an alternate way of achieving this.

Comment: Ooh I see -- that sounds messy but still doable, I'll use that if I end up needing to do this! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you like to create separate rows from a field with multiple URLs, it is usually not feasible in SQL, I suggest you use an ETL tool or some scripting language like python to do this.

Comment: Ahhh okay, I was hoping there was a way and I was just too much of a newbie to know it! Thanks for the input :)